Какие различия между ассиметричным шифрованием при подключении через SSH и ассиметричным шифрованием в HTTPS?
Как известно, протокол HTTPS использует ассиметричное шифрование. Чтобы лучше понять этот принцип, в этом вопросе я бы хотел сравнить ассиметричное шифрование в HTTPS с ассиметричным шифрованием при подключении к VPS через SSH.
Ассиметричное шифрование при подключении к VPS через SSH

Клиент и сервер обмениваются публичными ключами, при этом на клиенте этот ключ надо сознательно изготовить, а изготовление и использование публичного ключа на сервере происходит без сознательного вмешательства администратора.
С помощью публичных ключей можно только зашифровать данные, а для расшифровки нужны приватные ключи. Приватный ключ для клиента надо, опять же, изготовить сознательно, а сервере он имеется изначально.
Для того, чтобы подключиться к VPS с другого терминала, нужно изготовить на нём новую пару ключей и загрузить публичный на сервер.

Ассиметричное шифрование в HTTPS
Тут я на момент задавания вопроса знаю гораздо меньше, потому многое, что написано ниже - догадки и вопросы.

Сертификат - это аналог открытого ключа, однако хранится он исключительно на сервере.
"Закрытый ключ" в данном случае вроде как тоже называется "закрытым ключом" и также хранится исключительно на сервере.
При отправке HTTPS-запроса браузер запрашивает сертификат и по этому сертификату браузер делает заключение, можно ли доверять серверу.
Шифрование данных запроса на клиенте осуществляется... с помощью сертификата, полученного от сервера?
Расшифровка данных запроса на сервере осуществляется... с помощью того же закрытого ключа?
Шифрование данных ответа на сервере осуществляется... с того же сертификата?

Ну а чем браузер расшифровывает ответ от сервера, тут даже уже нет догадок, но надеюсь, что благодаря Вашим замечательным ответам удастся разложить всё по полочкам.

https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-happens-in-a-tls-handshake/ В процессе «рукопожатия» клиент и сервер создают ключ для симметричного шифрования и дальше пользуются из для передачи данных. У клиента нет своего асимметричного ключа, всё шифрование использует ключ (сертификат) сервера. Подлинность сервера проверяется цифровой подписью сертификата.

В ssh, кстати, ключи тоже используются только на начальном этапе что бы создать ключ для симметричного шифрования.

Вот на этом сайте ответ на ваш вопрос https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.emaro-ssl.ru/blog/zashchita-sayta-ssl/raznitsa-mezhdu-simmetrichnym-i-asimmetrichnym-shifrovaniem/&ved=2ahUKEwjM_5rriOqGAxWOPBAIHfeTA1gQFnoECCMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw39RgL5Z9h8LdJsJD2ukEmf
